# Visualizing chatbot structure

Tags: json, chatbot

I have created a chatbot using Snatchbot for the purpose of a quiz. I have been asked to create a dynamic decision tree structure for the chatbot which must be displayed on the web page, i.e. everytime the user answers a question, a branch on the tree must be created according the user's response. Is there anyway to do this? Is it possible to generate the JSON for the structure of the chatbot rather than the JSON for previous conversations? Would any other platform such as dialogflow be more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using SnatchBot, you will need to use the NLP section to create all your samples and train your Data, then you could add global connections, Giving the possibility to direct the bot to the needed subject at any point of the conversation.

The value of this tool is that it allows the user to immediately (and at any point in the conversation) direct the bot to a particular subject.

Comment: Using this approach, would it be possible for me to construct a tree which will be displayed on the web page? Would i have to use something like d3.js for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

**Technical perspective**, I have some recommendations for you:

https://jorin.me/chatbots.pdf (Development and Applications)
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325607065_Implementation_of_a_Chat_Bot_System_using_AI_and_NLP (Implementation Using AI And NLP)

**Strategy perspective**, here are the crucial 6 different main criteria for enterprise chatbot implementation success:

- Defining clear audience profiles of the project
- Identifying clear goal for the project
- Defining clear Dialog-flow Key Intents Related
- Platform’s Customer Experience SWOT assessment Forming coherent teams
- Testing and involving the audience from early on in the validation of
  the project
- Implementing feedback analytics to be used as basis for
  continuous improvement

(Source: http://athenka.com)